# Sort cells with RANK formula

Tags: excel, sorting, rank

I have several tables for weekly results, with the names being the same each week and listed alphabetically like this:

```
Week 1
Bob     18
John    21
Sally   3
Tom     19
```

These results are then fed into a "Total" table that calculates each person's results for all the different weekly tables. I have used the RANK formula to calculate each person's final rank, but it is not listed in order, it looks like this:

```
Results
Name   Rank
Bob     3
John    4
Sally   1
Tom     2
```

If I sort the Rank column from smallest to largest, the names are not tied to the rank, and the RANK formula is no longer calculating the rank for the correct people. How do I fix this so that it sorts the Rank column like this:

```
Results
Name   Rank
Sally   1
Tom     2
Bob     3
John    4
```

Comment: uh... sort on both column A and column B with B as the primary key?

Comment: Include the name column in your sort?

Comment: So the issue seems to be that I am sorting based on a formula based on the value in another cell, like cell A2=B4, so when I sort the cells in column A2, A2 still equals B4 so the value doesn't change. I am doing this so that I can dynamically update the spreadsheet and have the ranks change with them, but the sorting doesn't seem to cooperate with that model.

Comment: Create another sheet with Column A being ranks 1,2,3.... Then lookup the person with the corresponding rank. This may be a hack, but will work.

Comment: I am sure AGGREGATE with formula 14 or 15 could be used here to sort but that might be overkill